# How choose which column put on axis like label?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a csv file like this:

```
10557,1925080,1236052,1210752,1182492
11254,3159084,2264460,2187584,2144416
11334,2348036,1540692,1504536,1458332
11456,1607704,993228,974676,960308 
.....
```

I want create a chart with these data. I want use the first column as x-axes label, and put all other column like different line inside the chart. how can I do it?

This is my code

```
 set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 2.0 size 1680, 1024
 set size 1,1 
 set ylabel '[y]'
 set xlabel '[FIRST COLUMN FROM CSV]'
 set datafile separator ","
 set autoscale fix
 set key top left
 set key box
 set output 'Figure1.png'
plot  \
"figure1.csv" using 2 w l linewidth 3 lc rgb "black" title "second colum", \
"figure1.csv" using 3 w l linewidth 3 lc rgb "black" title "third colum", \
"figure1.csv" using 4 w l linewidth 3 dashtype 2 title "fourth colum", \
"figure1.csv" using 5 w l linewidth 3 dashtype 5 title "fifth colum"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get evenly spaced tics on the x-axis which get labelled with the values from the first column use `xticlabels`:

```
plot "figure.csv" using 0:2:xticlabels(1)
```